# Can this be done in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

We are looking at using SharePoint for some architect projects.
Right now we have to create a list of directories (11 to be exact and sub directories),for each project or building we build. Could we setup SharePoint to have some sort of template or automation that will build and name these directories? as well as ask what users we would like to be able to access it when it is created?

I understand that this question may already be answered (somewhere out there) however I may not be using the correct search terms. Ive used terms like "SharePoint auto build directories", "SharePoint library template" and related terms like that.

Any help is much appreciated. And any examples of how to do this can be done is even better.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Is this an onPremises installation or is it in the cloud?

Comment: Yes you can definitly create site template to render on-click implementation of what you desire.. you can control the permissions as well.

Comment: Right now its in the cloud. But if we have to we can probably move it on-premises. Is there a difference for what you can do? @Daniel

Comment: To accomplish what i would like would i need Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I creates a new site and made all the file directories I needed. I assigned the permissions and made it a template. All they have to do is create a new site and apply the template and everything they need to get started is right there.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example site that has all the web parts and lists I want on The projekt sites.

Then i export the site as a template and activate it on my project "main site" in "templates and page layouts".

I made a custom modal dialog to create projekt.  Where the user enters projectname, members, projectleader and so on.
And i have searched all templates available in this site and showen them. So the user can choose the projecttemplate in the modal.

On save the javascript creates a subsite from the template(which creates the web parts and lists). If successful create three groups and take the users from the userinputfields in modal.

Comment: That is awesome! do you have a link so i can take a look?

Answer (score -2):

You could create a custom column for associating the directory listing, and use audience targeting to control who view it. (Perhaps a user group or individuals.)